# How to update through select mysql

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have 2 date fields. One works perfectly (**created**) and the second (**transactiontime**) lags slightly. Therefore, I want to use my created date, which is in unix time and convert by using from_unixtime to set ind it to the field (transactiontime)

```
transactionsid         created            transactiontime
1                      1362140510         2013-06-06 16:55:21
2                      1362501952         1980-02-01 13:25:52
3                      1362502022         1980-02-02 14:20:10    
3                      1364224671         0
and so on, and so on
```

This is how i tried. But this wont work, because it wont let me define t3, why is this happening? And is there a simpler way?

```
UPDATE transactions as t1
set t1.transactiontime = 
(
select FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.created) 
from transactions as t2 
where t2.transactiontime < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
) as t3
where t1.transactionid = t3.transactionid
```

Comment: Try `UPDATE transactions as t1
set t1.transactiontime = FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.created) 
where t2.transactiontime < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: is this not working ?


UPDATE transactions SET transactiontime = FROM_UNIXTIME(created) WHERE transactiontime < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use subquery or JOIN to update table with data from same table. Much simpler and faster:

```
UPDATE transactions SET transactiontime=FROM_UNIXTIME(created) 
WHERE transactiontime < '2011-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Arh, thanks @Maris. I will accept you answer within 8 minutes :)

Answer (score -2):

```
UPDATE transactions 
SET transactiontime = created 
WHERE id = 1
```

Should work perfect

Comment: Yeah my bad forgot the UNIXTIME part